# Ra-data-simple-rest is not working | ERROR: total is not a number and newRecords.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, react-admin

I am trying to follow the tutorial and I am now at the part where I have to implement
my own REST-API. My format is identical to the needed format described in the tutorial.
Here my response: [The response from my API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjqbd.png)

The needed format looks like this:

```
// {
//     data: [
//         { id: 126, title: "allo?", author_id: 12 },
//         { id: 127, title: "bien le bonjour", author_id: 12 },
//         { id: 124, title: "good day sunshine", author_id: 12 },
//         { id: 123, title: "hello, world", author_id: 12 },
//         { id: 125, title: "howdy partner", author_id: 12 },
//     ],
//     total: 27
// }
```

But for some reason I always get the error that (1) total is not a number, but postman says it is. And (2) that newRecords.forEach is not a function.

´´´

```
//App.js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';
import styles from './App.css';
import SimpleFlow from './diagramm';
import { RuleList, PostList} from './rules';

//http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:3000/api');
const App = () =>
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} dashboard={SimpleFlow}>
        <Resource name="rules" list={RuleList} />
    </Admin>;

export default App;
```

´´´

´´´

```
//rules.js
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EmailField, DateField, Pagination } from 'react-admin'; 

export const RuleList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} perPage={25}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="Bezeichnung" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>

);
```

´´´

Comment: can you show the code of how you are reading `api response`

Comment: Please show your attempts so we can help you find where it went wrong. Without seeing any code, my guess is that you are trying to access the data before it has been returned from the API

Comment: Im just following the tutorial, so I dont think Im doing something unusual. But I gonna post the rest of the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to your data sample format, in that case your [API respose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjqbd.png) it is an object, but it need to be an array instead. Like this:

```
[
     { id: 126, title: "allo?", author_id: 12 },
     { id: 127, title: "bien le bonjour", author_id: 12 },
     { id: 124, title: "good day sunshine", author_id: 12 },
     { id: 123, title: "hello, world", author_id: 12 },
     { id: 125, title: "howdy partner", author_id: 12 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you re trying to render the data when it is still fetching.  && render the data

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the documentation is a bit confusing. In some places it says it wants the "total" and "success" properties in the response, and some places just the array. At the end is just a matter of adjusting the response. In my case I just took the "total" off the response and it works perfectly.